# Exception Handling with ELMAH - Inner Exception is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I just recently got put on a project at my company which uses ELMAH in an C# MVC project that uses .NET 4.6.2.  I've never used ELMAH before so this question may be dumb but I haven't been able to find any answer to this specific issue on this site or via Google.

The project uses ELMAH to log exceptions to a SQL database.  The database table contains fields for the application, host, exception type, source, message, and an AllXml column (among others).  The vast majority of the logged errors I understand and I'm working to debug.

However, semi-regularly there is an exception that is logged with the type **System.Exception**, the source column empty, and the message is simply **Inner exception is null**.  If I check the XML it contains this at the beginning:

```
<error   host="*hostname*"   
         type="System.Exception"   
         message="Inner exception is null"   
         detail="System.Exception: Inner exception is null"   
         user="*logged in user*"   
         time="2019-10-09T10:44:07.9624247Z">
```

If I dig through the XML more, I can find the exact controller, and method, that is throwing the exception.  However, the specific method does not have a `try-catch` block.  So I'm assuming that occasional this method is causing an exception which is being caught globally from ELMAH.

My question is, is there some way that I can modify the ELMAH configuration (either from the web.config file, initialization code, etc.) so that if the inner exception is `null` I can find out what the real exception is?  With the above error information (i.e. just `System.Exception` and a message of `Inner exception is null`) I have no way of determine what the cause is.

Any help, suggestions, or links to similarly report issues being resolved, would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but doesn't ELMAH include the stack trace of the thrown exception?

Comment: @ThomasArdal  Yes, all the other exceptions caught include a stack trace that is included in the "detail" property of the <error> tag.  But for this issue, the "detail" property only says "System.Exception: Inner exception is null".  That is why I'm having so much trouble debugging because I can't figure out where it is being thrown from.

Comment: Ah yeah that was what you wrote ;) have you tried searching for “Inner exception is null” in your code? It isn’t something that ELMAH logs to my knowledge.

Comment: I finally managed to find it.  There was a piece of code buried somewhere deep in one of the referenced libraries which was writing the exception, which is why I was unable to find it using the Find control in VS.  Turns out it was designed to write "Inner exception is null" to the database whenever a 404 error was returned from the WCF service - don't ask me why though, because I have no idea...lol.  Thanks for trying to assist.

Comment: That was my point. That someone was throwing an exception with that message :) Happy you found the cause 